# MobaXterm opens a black (cmd) window moxt2.exe at every new opened tab

Tags: windows

MobaXterm opens a black (cmd) window moxt2.exe at every new opening tab. If I close the additional moxt2.exe window, it also closes the associated tab from MobaXTerm.

The program runs fine for a few weeks, but yesterday began to keep open that annoying window.

It also opened an XWin.exe window but that I have managed to keep it closed by disable X server, from Settings->Configuration->X11.

How can I make MobaXterm run as it should, without open a new moxt2.exe window at every new ssh session?

Answer (score 7):

I was able to correct the problem by running the **MobaXterm_Professional_7.3.exe** program in Windows 7 compatibility mode. After that, no more extra empty windows appears in the background.

Answer (score 5):

Steps to resolve this issue:

1. Go to C:\Program Files (x86)\Mobatek\MobaXterm Personal Edition
2. Right click on application (MobaXterm)
3. Go to compatibility tab Check compatibility mode and select windows 7.
4. Restart MobaXterm.

You will not get any command prompt on opening new tab.
Hope this will help!